# Upgrade to Apps Script new IDE after downgrading

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

I must have at some point opted to use the legacy editor for apps script and now I have no idea how to switch back.

Google tells you how to downgrade but I couldn't find information on how to upgrade. Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my user interface, there is a button which upon click allows you to switch to the new editor:

[image: example]

and you can also switch back to the legacy editor if you want to:

[image]

You can go back and forth as many times you want, the only "annoying" thing is that an Editor Opt-out Survey appears every time you switch back to the old (legacy) editor.

Note that if you don't see that option, it means that the new editor is not available yet in your domain or account. It can very well be that your G Suite account for example does not have that option yet. You just need to wait until it will be available.

Comment: Yes I don't have that button, so I will have to hope that one day I will see it! Thanks Marios.